# Can we have absolute namespace in function definition if return type is an object in C++?

Tags: c++, object, namespaces, return, declaration

Let us consider a function `bar` declared in namespace `foo` which returns a `std::vector< float >` (but also works with other objects).

```
// header.h
#include <vector>

namespace foo
{
        ::std::vector< float > bar();
}
```

Compiling its definition using relative namespace works.

```
#include "header.h"

::std::vector< float > foo::bar()
{
}
```

However, compiling its definition using absolute namespace does not work.

```
#include "header.h"

::std::vector< float > ::foo::bar()
{
}
```

Return error from GCC is

```
function.cpp:3:26: error: ‘foo’ in ‘class std::vector<float>’ does not name a type
::std::vector< float > ::foo::bar()
```

It turns out that spaces are allowed in namespacing, so, `::std::vector< float > ::foo::bar()` is equivalent to `::std::vector< float >::foo::bar()`. How can I use absolute namespace in function definition when return type is an object?

Comment: `::std::vector< float > ::foo::bar()` is being treated as `::std::vector< float >::foo::bar()`.  The white space is ignored.

Comment: `auto ::foo::bar() -> ::std::vector< float > { ... }`

Comment: Nice, I didn't thought about it.

Comment: @n.m., that comment deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
::std::vector< float > (::foo::bar)()
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't that we could write like that.

Comment: That looks ugly. Prefer sticking the return type on the right to get passed that ugly parse.

Answer (score 7):

One way to resolve the problem is to use trailing return type.

```
auto ::foo::bar() -> ::std::vector< float >
{
    ...
}
```